# Sample Letter vs Letter Sample

Tags: compound-nouns

I am wondering if "sample letter" and "letter sample" have the same meaning. I have tried googling but couldn't find any information.

Comment: In your context, ***letter*** and ***sample*** are two nouns, either of which could in principle be used to modify the other. A *sample letter* (1) is a letter of type "sample", and a *letter sample* (2) is a sample of type "letter". That second meaning would require a fairly contrived context, so *in practice* many people would just assign it the first interpretation anyway. But things would be very different with, say, a ***house brick*** (a brick of the type used to build houses) and a ***brick house*** (a house built with bricks, rather than some other construction material).

Answer (score 2):

These activate different meanings of the word sample.

A sample letter is an example [missive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/missive) (that you might want to base your letter on)

> Use the sample letter on page 63, and write a formal letter of application to a business school.

A letter sample is a selection (perhaps a random selection) of letters.  From some source.

> To train the neural network we too a letter sample of 1000 letters from the examples of MNIST examples of handwriting.

Answer (score 2):

A **sample letter** has essentially the same meaning as *example letter*.  We use the phrase when we mean, "Here is an example of the kind of letter you should write. Imitate it closely." I frequently give my students a **sample essay** to show them my expectations.

The same would be roughly true of a **sample house.** A person who sells houses might say, "Come see our sample house. We will build one like it for you, perhaps with some differences that you may choose."

The pattern **X sample** means something very different. It does not mean an example of something to be imitated. It means that we have taken a small piece of the whole thing. Its purpose is to represent the whole.

A **blood sample** is a small amount of blood that a doctor uses to diagnose illnesses. A few ml represents all of the blood in the patient, which reflects the patient's health in general.

A **paint sample** is a small amount of paint on a stiff piece of paper. It represents all of the paint that can be made using the same formula.

So a  **letter sample** might mean a small piece of a letter. I can imagine that a person who specializes in rare documents might take a **letter sample** to determine the age of the whole letter. Personally, I would probably call it "a sample of the letter," but I do not specialize in such work, so I do not know if **letter sample** is ever used in this sense by professionals. It is simply the only context in which I can imagine the phrase being used.